# initialize data table located in html page from another javascript file function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables

I have added data table in html page with all js and css files.
Now what I want is to initialize that data table from another javascript file function which has ajax call to get data from webservice, so that I will assign that data to data table.

> report.js

```
      function getReport(projectname){   // added for data table plugin 

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:webCallUrl,
            complete:function(data){        
            },error:function(){

            }

        })

    }
```

> test1.html

```
     <div id="graphic12">
      <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#graphic').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

        console.log(dataArr);

        var table=$('#example').DataTable( { 
            "aaData": dataArr,
            "aoColumns": [
                {"title": "organization"},
                {"title": "project"},
                {"title": "open_tickets"}
                ]
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). As far as I know this plug-in has build in option for this. Otherwise use promises:

```
function getReport(projectname) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: webCallUrl,
    complete: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
  })
}

getReport().then(function (dataArr) {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "aaData": dataArr,
    "aoColumns": [
      {"title": "organization"},
      {"title": "project"},
      {"title": "open_tickets"}
    ]
  });
})
```